# SSRS Table headers

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How to add textboxes from previous pages in SSRS ?

Ex:

```
       Page1 : Textbox(page1)
       Page2 : Textbox(page1) + Textbox(Page2)
       Page3 : Textbox(page2) + Textbox(Page3)
```

Textbox is in table header.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean? Is this in the details or in the header? Can you please provide more information?

Comment: Textbox is in group header..Value should be additive. Ex : Current value  of textbox = Current value  of textbox + previous value of textbox